# Android Studio: Always build with gradlew compileDebug

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-build

Is there a way to customize Android Studio so that Gradle always runs with the compileDebug flag?

Anyone running the new Android Studio has likely seen the following error.  The only solution I've found is to run gradlew compileDebug from the command line.  Keeping a console window open all the time is a very poor workflow.  Is there no way to display build errors within the IDE?

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TestProj:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a default task? http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html  (I don't know if this will work) Personally, I always keep a command line window open - I like to keep my SCM and builds separate from my code and IDE.